# Android BroadcastReceiver: perform network call and play sound

Tags: android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am writing an alarm application. I have a `BroadcastReceiver`, which I am using with the `AlarmService` to handle the alarms going off.

In the `BroadcastReceiver`, I want to perform a network call, and then if some conditions are met, play a sound using the `SoundPool`.

However, network calls are not allowed in the thread running the `BroadcastReceiver`, so I am getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I tried using an `IntentService`, which is executed on a background thread, which get me around the network call problem. However, I have not managed to play a sound from it, and getting:

```
W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.media.SoundPool$EventHandler) {d64695a} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.media.SoundPool$EventHandler) {d64695a} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
```

My understanding is that the `SoundPool` playing the sounds plays asynchronously, and the thread has died.

How is it possible, starting from a `BroadcastReceiver` to perform both the network call and invoke the `SoundPool`?

**UPDATE**

This is the first version of the code, where I am trying to make the HTTP call inside the `BroadcastReceiver`. After that is the exception I am receiving. Note that, although the part playing the sound is never reached here, it does work if I skip the HTTP call.

```
package com.marksoft.alarm.alarm.events;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.SoundPool;

import com.marksoft.alarm.R;
import com.marksoft.alarm.alarm.data.IAlarmRepository;
import com.marksoft.alarm.alarm.data.InMemoryAlarmRepository;
import com.marksoft.alarm.backend.myApi.model.Prediction;
import com.marksoft.alarm.tfl.TflService;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.List;

public class BusStopCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(com.marksoft.alarm.alarm.events.BusStopCheckReceiver.class);
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private TflService tflService = new TflService();
    private IAlarmRepository alarmRepository = InMemoryAlarmRepository.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // ...
        if(shouldSoundAlarm()) {
            playSound(context);
        }
        // ...
    }

    private boolean shouldSoundAlarm() {
        // HTTP call
        List<Prediction> predictions = tflService.getBusStopArrivals(alarm.getStopId());

        for(Prediction prediction : predictions) {
            LOG.info("Checking prediction {}", prediction);
            if(...) {
                LOG.info("Should sound alarm for prediction {}", prediction);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private int playSound(final Context context) {
        // Load the sound
        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setAudioAttributes(attributes).build();
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
                LOG.info("Played sound");
            }
        });
        return soundPool.load(context, R.raw.bell1, 1);
    }
}
```

And the exception:

```
09-21 13:53:05.020 3218-3218/com.marksoft.alarm D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


        --------- beginning of crash
        09-21 13:53:05.021 3218-3218/com.marksoft.alarm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.marksoft.alarm, PID: 3218
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.marksoft.alarm.alarm.events.BusStopCheckReceiver: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3018)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1544)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
        Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.blockGuardOnNetwork(Platform.java:300)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1194)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1189)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.closeIfOwnedBy(Connection.java:148)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.closeIfOwnedBy(OkHttpClient.java:77)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.closeIfOwnedBy(HttpConnection.java:137)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.disconnect(HttpTransport.java:135)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.disconnect(HttpEngine.java:573)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.disconnect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.disconnect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:93)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.disconnect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:99)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.marksoft.alarm.tfl.TflService.getBusStopArrivals(TflService.java:78)
        at com.marksoft.alarm.alarm.events.BusStopCheckReceiver.shouldSoundAlarm(BusStopCheckReceiver.java:70)
        at com.marksoft.alarm.alarm.events.BusStopCheckReceiver.onReceive(BusStopCheckReceiver.java:55)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3011)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1544) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: can you, like, show the code, so we don't have to guess

Comment: I added the snippet from the first version of the code, where I am trying to make the HTTP call and play the sound from the `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: what is tflService.getBusStopArrivals?

Comment: The `tflService. getBusStopArrivals()` invokes a Google Cloud Endpoint, which is the network call causing the exception. I didn't think the code for that is relevant.

Comment: Is it a synchronous call?

Comment: Yes, it is synchronous.

Comment: have you verified that shouldSoundAlarm is actually true in the case where you say the sound is not played when it should?

Comment: The `shouldoundAlarm` never returns as it is, because the exception is thrown. When I hardcode the `return true;` the sound is heard.

Comment: oh right. Well you should definitely use a intentservice or jobservice to do the network request. Any clue why the sound was not playing when you were using the intentservice?

Comment: I guess it has to do with the `SoundPool` being async, and the `IntentService` thread being "dead" by the time it tries to play the sound. That's the exception I initially posted. So the `IntentService` allows me to make the HTTP call, but not play the sound :-(

Comment: Exactly. I would make a jobservice for this, do the network request asyncronously in a separate thread, and set a callback for it to know when you have to play the sound

Comment: As you suggested, I ended up creating an `IntentService` to make the HTTP call. However, since I was already using the `AlarmManager`, I stuck with it and created a `BroadcastReceiver` to play the sound (instead of introducing the `JobScheduler` too). Since my min version is 21, I will consider moving everything to the `JobScheduler`. You can write your suggestion as an answer, so that I can check it if you want. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just gave some tips. You can answer the question yourself with the solution you end up with!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can start an IntentService and on Completion of this intent service you can again start the broadcastReceiver by sendBroadCast and put some extra and its onReceive method get that extra match it and then play the sound.
SO this way you can sync the network call and play sound.

Comment: is this answer helpful to you..??